# Laravel 5 localhost installation not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just installed Laravel 5 in my local environment on Mac Yosemite. I've set up Laravel in a directory and then created an Apache Virtual Host to point to that directory.

The root of the project can now successfully be accessed by visiting `http://myproject.localhost.com`.  However, I don't see the Laravel welcome screen. Instead, I just see a blank white page, and I can't figure out why.

Chrome is showing a 500 Internal Server error when it tries to load the domain. The same thing happens if I try to access the index.php file directly: `http://myproject.localhost.com/index.php`.

I wanted to look in the Laravel error log to see what the issue is, but that left me even more confused because the `store/logs` directory is empty.

I know the virtual host setup is correct because when I point the virtual host to another project, that does not use Laravel, it works correctly. Also, I was previously receiving permission errors from the `vendor` directory, which I resolved. I thought that was the last issue that needed to be fixed before the welcome page would load correctly, but to my surprise, I only see a blank screen.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there any more information I can provide to help solve this?

Here is my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@slopes.localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/dev/slopes/public"
    ServerName slopes.localhost.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/slopes.localhost.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/slopes.localhost.com-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Users/myusername/dev/slopes/public">
         Require all granted
         AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access index.php in the browser, I see the request in `/private/var/log/apache2/slopes.localhost.com-access_log`, and it shows a 500 response. It produces no entries in `/private/var/log/apache2/slopes.localhost.com-error_log`.

Comment: is the vhost pointing to the public directory? root/public

Comment: what are the permissions of your `storage` directory and everything underneath it?

Comment: @watcher the permissions are: `drwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: @BrianDillingham yes it's pointing to the public directory. I even went into the `index.php` file and added some break points to echo out the word `test`, and it works up until line 51. After that line, I get the 500 error.

Comment: To ensure proper permissions, please post owner user and group, and the user Apache is run with And what about the Apache log? (error.log)

Comment: Owner is my user name. Group is `staff`. Apache is running with user `_www` and group `_www`. Nothing appears in the apache error logs though, which is why I did not think it was a permissions issue.

Comment: What about hosts file? Did you edit that one?

Comment: Yes, the host file is configured. When I look at the apache access logs, I can see the requests to `index.php`, but it is showing a 500 response. I can't find anything in any error logs though.

Comment: Try not using "subdomain" do something like project.dev and hosts should look like this `127.0.0.1 www.project.dev project.dev`, I remember that I had exactly same problems and I solved it with storage permissions, and composer dump-autoload... Check if php artisan commands work.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same thing (also Yosemite) and here's the solution to my issue, maybe it is yours too.
Edit the public/.htaccess, comment the following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

to

```
#<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
#    Options -MultiViews
#</IfModule>
```

Check if it works.

Edit:  Check your httpd-vhosts.conf file, does it looks something like this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin you
   ServerName www.myproject.localhost.com
   ServerAlias myproject.localhost.com
   DocumentRoot "/path/to/webfolder/laravel/public"
   ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
   CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Check your ErrorLog, if you don't have it, add it, something must be there since the 500 is being throwed by Apache. Also, double check you're pointing the root to the `public/` folder

**EDIT:** After chatting (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73694), @Kyslik figured out it was the lack of the mcrypt extension, guided a new php and mcrypt install  through brew. Then permission to `storage/` and it worked.

Comment: I don't have those lines in my `public/.htaccess` file.

Comment: Get the default .htaccess from the laravel package:  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess comment those lines and move it to the public folder.

Comment: Sorry, I did have those lines. I commented them out as you said, but it did not make a difference.

Comment: Try this other .htaccess from laravel:  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation#pretty-urls

Comment: Edited my answer, check your vhosts file please.

Comment: I added my virtual host to the question. Please review.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73694/discussion-between-hfingler-and-flyingl123).